# Prefixes dont work in dotNetRdf's LeviathanUpdateProcessor?

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf

I'm running an INSERT/WHERE statement with dotNetRdf using the LeviathanUpdateProcessor  and it works great but it doesnt recognize the PREFIX namespaces I add programmatically or the namespaces in the SPARQL.  I also added the into the SparqlUpdateCommandSet and the Graph object.

```
SparqlUpdateCommandSet cmds = parser.ParseFromString(cmdString);
            cmds.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace( ...)
```

Does anyone know if this works ? I can't use any prefixes otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces need to be defined in the actual string to be parsed rather than after the fact. The parser needs to expand them to complete URIs during the parsing process.

Namespaces added programmatically after-the-fact Will only be used when serialising the update back to a string.

If you prefer to manage your namespaces programmatically then you should look at using the [SparqlParameterizedString](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Querying%20with%20SPARQL#!representing-queries) as shown in the user guide.